# programatically start 5ghz wifi hotspot in android

Tags: android, wifi, bandwidth, hotspot, access-point

There doesn't seem a public API for managing WIFI Hotspot in android.

There are some solutions with reflection and others but none seems to answer

> How can I configure 5Ghz WiFi hotspot?

**I want to achieve faster file transfer with 5GHz local hotspot network between two android devices both supporting 5GHz band.**

3rd party apps like ShareIt **can** enable 5GHz hotspot in "Ultra Fast Mode"

Comment: Did you find an answer? Even I don't understand, how it does that. Heck, even Xender only works at 2.4GHz. Google files does it somehow too.

Comment: On newer android versions,only apps having same signature as system can modify hotspot configuration. (protection level signature). Only option is to start settings intent and ask user to do it

Comment: Yeah, already got that. But atleast, localonlyhotspot should be configurable. They are basically limiting all file transfer apps. They even specifically mentioned that apps can't view whole storage for allowing users to select files.

Comment: Google always disappoints when it comes to these so called "privacy friendly" changes